# Excel: Copying column values into two separate column for a similar value in another column

Tags: excel

I am wanting something like below in excel:

Convert:

```
ITEM_ID   CAT_ID
 1002      3278
 1002      2398
 1047      8743
 1047      1108
```

To:

```
ITEM_ID   CAT_ID_1   CAT_ID_2
 1002      3278       2398
 1047      8743       1108
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are looking to use what is called a Pivot Table.  Google this and you will find dozens (if not hundreds) of examples of how to do this in Excel.

Comment: @MartinParkin - not really *just* a pivot table - there is no "CAT_ID_x" in the data.

Answer (score 0):

Add a third column as shown below (enter the first cell's formula then fill down)

Then create a pivot table with rows="ITEM_ID" and columns="count"

[image]